# How to set source root directory via PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC environment variable when source collection is enabled

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-java

I'm trying to run my first Playwright trace using java and i'm getting below error, I'm not sure what i'm missing out and I'm running mu code in Intlij

```
Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
        Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
        BrowserContext browserContext = browser.newContext();
        browserContext.tracing().start(new Tracing.StartOptions().setScreenshots(true).setSnapshots(true).setSources(true));
        Page page = browser.newPage();
        page.navigate("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
```

I'm getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Source root directory must be specified via PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC environment variable when source collection is enabled
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.startImpl(TracingImpl.java:95)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.lambda$start$0(TracingImpl.java:69)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.lambda$withLogging$0(LoggingSupport.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.withLogging(LoggingSupport.java:47)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.withLogging(ChannelOwner.java:79)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.withLogging(LoggingSupport.java:35)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.start(TracingImpl.java:69)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Playwright to link your test sources to the trace log it needs to know the location of the source folder as described in the documentation [here](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/inspector#open-playwright-inspector).

For example in Powershell you can set it like this:

```
$env:PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC="src/test/java"
```

This will add the sources to the trace and to the Inspector.

If you do not need the sources, you can just disable it when you create the context instance:

```
context.tracing().start(new Tracing.StartOptions()
       .setScreenshots(true)
       .setSnapshots(true)
       .setSources(false));
```